Returning an optional from a templated conversion function
I would like to update conversion functions which have the following signatures:
template<typename In, typename Out>
bool Convert(const In& p_in, Out& p_out);

// Returns `true` if the conversion succeeded, `false` otherwise.

so that I could use std::optional instead. Something like (notice template parameters were switched):
template<typename Out, typename In>
std::optional<Out> Convert(const In& p_in);

There is a big change as far as templates are concerned: One of the templated type is now used in the return type of Convert. Because of this, compilation fails unless I specify function parameters. Example:
#include <optional>

class A
{
public:
    A() = default;

    A(int p_value)
    : m_value(p_value)
    {}

private:
    int m_value = 0;
};

template<typename In, typename Out>
bool Convert(const In& p_in, Out& p_out)
{
    return false;
}

template<>
bool Convert(const int& p_in, A& p_out)
{
    p_out = A(p_in);
    return true;
}

template<typename Out, typename In>
std::optional<Out> Convert2(const In& p_in)
{
    return std::nullopt;
}

template<>
std::optional<A> Convert2(const int& p_in)
{
    return A(p_in);
}

int main()
{
    const int in = 2;

    // Fine, but not ideal since we have `std::optional` available:
    A out;
    const bool result1 = Convert(in, out);

    // Failed:
    //const std::optional<A> result2 = Convert2(in);

    // Ok, but sadly A is repeated at called site:
    const std::optional<A> result3 = Convert2<A>(in);

    return 0;
}

Here is the error message (gcc) if I uncomment the second call:
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:62:46: error: no matching function for call to 'Convert2(const int&)'
   62 |     const std::optional<A> result2 = Convert2(in);
      |                                      ~~~~~~~~^~~~
<source>:30:20: note: candidate: 'template<class Out, class In> std::optional<_Tp> Convert2(const In&)'
   30 | std::optional<Out> Convert2(const In& p_in)
      |                    ^~~~~~~~
<source>:30:20: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:62:46: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'Out'
   62 |     const std::optional<A> result2 = Convert2(in);
      |                                      ~~~~~~~~^~~~

Using auto, I was able to get this to work:
template<typename In>
auto Convert(const In& p_in)
{
    return std::nullopt;
}

template<>
auto Convert(const int& p_in)
{
    return std::make_optional<A>(p_in);
}

This has the advantage of being usable as I want at call site:
const std::optional<A> result4 = Convert3(in)

But I feel the function signature is now very much less informative on what the function does. One has to read the implementation to know a std::optional<A> is returned.
Would there be a way to make this work, without having to specify templated types at call site?
template<typename Out, typename In>
std::optional<Out> Convert(const In& p_in)
{
    // ?
}

template<>
std::optional<A> Convert(const int& p_in)
{
    // ?
}

int main()
{
    const std::optional<A> result = Convert(in)

    return 0;
}

Sources on Godbolt : https://godbolt.org/z/bYjrcPsPx.

const auto result = Convert<A>(in);? An attempt to avoid A on the right looks really weird.

This does work, however you loose the std::optional information at call site. If possible, I would like to see it without having to go to the definition.

const std::optional result = Convert<A>(in); should also work thanks to CTAD if all Convert functions return some std::optional (std::nullopt is not std::optional).

In general I prefer function overloading for convert functions, because I find I usually need to be very precise in input type and desired output type. So if you ask me I think a function template may not be the most useful approach (this is me assuming you want to convert types, not values)

If you could use auto, that means you know the correct Out for each input type (e.g., A for int).  Is that true?

The natural way to update the code to use std::optional would be:
template <typename In, typename Out>
bool OldConvert(const In& p_in, Out& p_out);

template <typename Out, typename In>
std::optional<Out> Convert(const In& p_in)
{
    Out res;
    if (OldConvert(p_in, res)) { // Possibly put code directly here
        return std::make_optional(res);
    } else {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
}

and usage changes from
A out;
if (Convert(in, out)) {
    use(out);
}

to
if (const auto out = Convert<A>(in)) {
    use(*out);
}

whereas auto might be textually replaced by std::optional<A> (if you want to be explicit) or std::optional (to avoid repetition of A)
That seems idiomatic to me.
You have another alternative with (ab)use of converting operator to have the syntax:
if (const std::optional<A> out = Converter(in)) {
    use(*out);
}

with
template <typename In>
struct ConverterHelper
{
    template <typename Out>
    operator std::optional<Out>() && {
        return Convert<Out>(arg);
    }
    const In& arg;
};

template <typename In>
auto Converter(const In& p_in)
{
    return ConverterHelper{p_in};
}

Demo

template<class T>struct tag_t{};
template<class T>constexpr tag_t<T> tag={}; 

template<class F>
struct deduce_out {
  F f;
  template<class Out>
  operator Out()&&{
    return f(tag<Out>);
  }
};

Use:
template<class In>
auto convert(In&& in){
  return deduce_out{
  [&]<class Out>
  (tag_t<std::optional<Out>>)
  ->std::optional<Out>
  {
    // code
  }
}

std::optional<double> d = convert(7);


Two things:
First, you don't want to change the order of the template parameters. It should be:
template <typename In, typename Out>
std::optional<Out> convert( In input );

This will allow template type deduction on the input type, at least.
Second, when invoking the function, you'll have to explicitly specify the Out type, since there's nothing which would allow the compiler to deduce it. So:
X out = convert<X>( in );

The compiler doesn't (normally) use the return value when deducing template parameters.
It's actually possible to get the compiler to deduce the Out type, but it's rarely worth the added complexity. The compiler will consider the targeted for conversions, so the actual convert function would look something like:
template <typename In>
Helper<In> convert( In value ) { return Helper<In>( value ); }

The Helper class would then contain a number of conversion operators:
template <typename In>
class Helper
{
    X m_value;
public:
    Helper( X value ) : m_value( value ) {}
    template <typename Out>
    operator std::optional<Out>()
    {
        //  actual conversion of m_value here.
    }
};

In general, however, implementing this for more than a few types would be extremely painful, and in general, I don't think this would make life that much easier for the user: you couldn't write things like:
auto tmp = convert( anX );
if ( tmp.has_value() ) {
    Y value = tmp.value();
    //  ....
}

(This is probably a case of abuse of auto, but some people do seem to prefer it. It does avoid having to spell out std::optional.)

With template <typename In, typename Out> it will not be possible to do X out = convert<X>( in ); and let In be deduced. The other way around would work though.

Your first point is incorrect.  Out should be first: in can still be deduced.
